# One `onClickListener` for many buttons in kotlin?

Tags: android, button, kotlin, onclicklistener

How to create one `onClickListener` for many buttons in kotlin, i know there is already a solutin for it in Java but how to do it in kotlin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `OnClickListener` interface at class level and perform the actions by checking the button's ids in overridden method i.e. `onClick(v: View?)` as follows

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button1)
        val button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
        button1.setOnClickListener(this)
        button2.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {

        when (v?.getId()) {
            R.id.button1 -> firstFun()
            R.id.button2 -> secondFun()
        }
    }

    private fun firstFun() {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    private fun secondFun() {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

In my example, it increases the value of the number on the screen by one after the user clicks. I believe you can do the same for your problem. You can do so by using the following code.

```
 val buttonShow=findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_id)
 val numberText=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_id)
 var count=0
 buttonShow.setOnCickListener{
    count++
    numberText.text=count.toString()
}
```